# Command in sudoers file?

Tags: linux, sudoers

I am adding below command in sudoers file, but it is giving me syntax error not allowing "foo=bar" before command.

```
user   ALL=(runas) SETENV:NOPASSWD:foo=bar /path/to/command /path/to/script
```

If I add using /bin/bash prefix this worked

```
user   ALL=(runas) SETENV:NOPASSWD:/bin/bash -c "foo=bar /path/to/command /path/to/script"
```

but when I run `sudo` from user it asks me for a password.
Can someone please let me know How should this work?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your command list must be a file in your filesystem indicated its full path. I´m not quite sure what your `foo=bar "command"` should even mean. If that is a variable being set, aren´t you lacking a semicolon (`foo=bar;`)? But anyways, sudo is not about setting variables either way, it´s about running commands. You should just get rid of foo=bar altogether and keep

```
user   ALL=(runas) SETENV:NOPASSWD: /path/to/command /path/to/script
```

You wouldn´t use sudo to stop a user from setting a variable (if that is what you even meant in the first place).

from manpages:

> A Cmnd_List is a list of one or more command names, directories, and
>   other aliases.  A command name is a fully qualified file name which
>   may include shell-style wildcards (see the Wildcards section below).